# libgdx: Why do all my actors not render when I add an actor using Shaperenderer?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am adding an actor to a group which causes all my actors to not show. The actors draw method is using Shaperenderer as shown below

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.rectLine(ax, ay, bx, by, 5);
    shapeRenderer.end();
}
```

Whenever I remove the actor all the other actors in the group show without a problem. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't interleave the begin/end of a SpriteBatch and a ShapeRenderer. When an actor's draw method is called, `begin()` has already been called on the SpriteBatch. So you can fix your `draw()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    batch.end();
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.rectLine(ax, ay, bx, by, 5);
    shapeRenderer.end();
    batch.begin();
}
```

Also make sure you've set the projection matrix for the shape renderer.

Note that you are causing an extra SpriteBatch flush for every actor that does this.